# A problem on super/sub martingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales

Let $(X_n, \mathscr{F_n}), n \geq 0$ be a super martingale and $T$ an $\{F_n\}$-stopping time a.s. bounded by $N \lt \infty$. Show that

$$ E[|X_T|] \leq 3 \max_{n \leq N} E[|X_n|]$$

I can prove that   $$ E[|X_T|] \leq  E[\max_{n \leq N} |X_n|]$$. I am confused about how to get $3$ in the RHS.

Comment: It might be a good idea to add your proof (or at least the idea of your proof) to the question.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread the second inequality.

Comment: It might be a good idea to add your proof (or at least the idea of your proof) that, if X is a super-martingale then |X| is a sub-martingale (a result which seems quite wrong at first sight).